# The pen join style not applied on all corners of a shape

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

[image: Line joins]

The shape is drawn with the `Polyline()` function.
The relevant code is here:

```
void DoDrawing(HWND hwnd) {

    LOGBRUSH brush;
    COLORREF col = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    DWORD pen_style = PS_SOLID | PS_JOIN_MITER | PS_GEOMETRIC;

    brush.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;
    brush.lbColor = col;
    brush.lbHatch = 0;       

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    HPEN hPen1 = ExtCreatePen(pen_style, 8, &brush, 0, NULL);
    HPEN holdPen = SelectObject(hdc, hPen1);

    POINT points[5] = { { 10, 30 }, { 100, 30 }, { 100, 100 }, { 10, 100 }, {10, 30}};
    Polyline(hdc, points, 5);
    DeleteObject(hPen1);

    SelectObject(hdc, holdPen);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);  
}
```

The `PS_JOIN_MITER` is applied on three corners but not on the top-left corner. On that corner the default `PS_JOIN_ROUND` is used. How to fix this?

The following is a full working example:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void DoDrawing(HWND);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Pens";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Line joins",
          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
          100, 100, 250, 180, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

  return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(msg) {

        case WM_PAINT:

            DoDrawing(hwnd);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:

            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void DoDrawing(HWND hwnd) {

    LOGBRUSH brush;
    COLORREF col = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    DWORD pen_style = PS_SOLID | PS_JOIN_MITER | PS_GEOMETRIC;

    brush.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;
    brush.lbColor = col;
    brush.lbHatch = 0;       

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    HPEN hPen1 = ExtCreatePen(pen_style, 8, &brush, 0, NULL);
    HPEN holdPen = SelectObject(hdc, hPen1);

    POINT points[5] = { { 10, 30 }, { 100, 30 }, { 100, 100 }, { 10, 100 }, {10, 30}};
    Polyline(hdc, points, 5);
    DeleteObject(hPen1);

    SelectObject(hdc, holdPen);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);  
}
```

Comment: Rounded rectangles in GDI...If you are as anal about pixel perfection as I am, then this is just the first of your problems, believe me. (Take a look at some of my questions...I've asked a few about rectangle rounding too, but from C#)

Comment: It supposed to be an educational example of how line joins work. The same happens when drawing a triangle -- the join style is not applied on the first corner.

Comment: Are you sure that's the first corner, or the last corner? This is an important question (it has to do with figure closing behavior).

Comment: @andlabs not sure here, I was referring to the shape from how I see it on the picture, not from the technical point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Polyline` does not join the first and last point.

Use `Polygon(hdc, points, 5)` instead of `Polyline`

Also, select the oldPen in to DC before deleting the existing pen, in this order:

```
SelectObject(hdc, holdPen);
DeleteObject(hPen1);
```

(although Windows will forgive you if you don't do it in the right order)